# How to create sql query results in columns from rows?

Tags: oracle

From the following tables:

```
store(store_id, ...) {1 ..., 2 ...} two stores
film(film_id, ...)
inventory(inventory_id, film_id, store_id)
rental(rental_id, rental_date, inventory_id, return_date, ...)
category(category_id, name)
film_category(film_id, category_id)
film(film_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, ...)
customer(customer_id, store_id, ...)
```

Can I have a query result on a table just like the following?

```
CategoryName | "Store 1: available items" | "Store 1: unavaliable items" | "Store 2: avaliable items" | "Store 2: unavaliable items"
```

Notice that the store fields in the result table are in separate columns not in the same columns !!

I am not looking for the result query, I am looking for how to make them side by side store 1, store 2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the energy to deal with all the joins through all your tables, but the general idea would be to join to the store table twice and check the results.

```
 SELECT f.film_id,
   CASE when store1.store_id is not null then 'Item exists in store 1' else 'Item missing from store 1' END as 'Store 1 Status'
 FROM film f
 LEFT OUTER JOIN store store1 on f.film_id = store1.film_id AND store1.store_id = 1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN store store2 on f.film_id = store2.film_id AND store2.store_id = 2
```

This doesn't scale well if you had 100 stores, but for two it wouldn't be evil.

Hope that helps.